# How to stop an endless loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am making a script game and use this code for multiple choice.

```
while True:
d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Befriend Fred. B) Be mean to Fred. [A/B]? : ")
if d1a == "A":
    print ("You befriend fred. You now have a friend..")
elif d1a == "B":
    print ("You angered Fred. He kills you. RIP.")
elif d1a == "Q" :
    break
```

After this happens,If you type A or B it will print the desired text and then ask you again "Do you want to befriend fred?" etc.

Comment: Just use `break` after first two conditions.

Comment: and fix your indentation.

Comment: There's no reason for this code to be in a loop

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I hope this indentation is what the OP originally had since this is python.. When `d1a == "Q"` is fired, it will break out of the loop.

Comment: I dont understand the need for a loop here

Comment: @PatrickHaugh and woodhead92 - The reason for a loop is that an invalid input will cause it to run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `break` statements to each conditional:

```
while True:
    d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Befriend Fred. B) Be mean to Fred. [A/B]? : ")
    if d1a == "A":
        print ("You befriend fred. You now have a friend..")
        break
    elif d1a == "B":
        print ("You angered Fred. He kills you. RIP.")
        break
    elif d1a == "Q" :
        break
```

Also if you want to leave the loop after one iteration the loop isn't necessary. However, I assume you're looping until you get the correct input, in which case it might be nice to tell your player that the input was incorrect:

```
while True:
    d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Befriend Fred. B) Be mean to Fred. [A/B]? : ")
    if d1a == "A":
        print ("You befriend fred. You now have a friend..")
        break
    elif d1a == "B":
        print ("You angered Fred. He kills you. RIP.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input")
```

Comment: you should fix your indentation

Comment: 1) Your indentation is wrong, and 2) you can flag/vote to close duplicate questions.

Comment: Copied directly from OP - didn't notice it was incorrect initially.